# upload multiple files , enctype=“multipart/form-data”

Tags: file, http, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I want to upload multiple files to the controller but its taking only one.

I am using multipart for file transfer.
How to get the multiple files to the controller side.
I am not able to access bytes and filename. Its throwing errors,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home/step38/uploadReport", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadReport(                 
         @RequestParam(value = "fileName") List<MultipartFile> files,
         @RequestParam(value = "pLogId") String pLogId,
          HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) 
{ 
    int applicationNameId = 0;
   String fileName;
    String typeOption = "Raw Particle Data";
    for(MultipartFile file:files)      
     fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

    logger.debug("step3.1 upload particle count -- Start");

    ModelAndView modelAndView = createModelAndView(ToogleStep.step38);
    setCurrentStep(session, modelAndView, ToogleStep.step38);
    String view = "redirect:/home/step38";
    modelAndView.setViewName(view);   

    try 
    {
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute(Constants.USER_DB);
        Project current_project = (Project) session.getAttribute(Constants.PROJECT);
        Credential credential = (Credential) session.getAttribute(Constants.AUTH_USER);            
        boolean checkOK = true;        

        if (current_project != null && SystemUtils.projectEditable(current_project, credential)) 
        {
            long projectId = current_project.getId();

            if(checkOK)
            {
               byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();      
                HashMap<String,String> options= new HashMap<String,String>();
               //added pLogId in the options(this will contain demoToogleFileInfoId)           
                options.put(ToogleReportDataConstants.TTL_PROCESS_LOG_ID_OPTION,pLogId);
                String toogleFileId = reportService.uploadReport(user, projectId, fileName, typeOption, bytes, applicationNameId, options);

            }
        }         
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looping through at the right location. 
try looping it after you have your modelAndView(view)

```
 int applicationNameId = 0;
        String typeOption = "Raw Particle Data";
        ModelAndView modelAndView = createModelAndView(ToogleStep.step38);
        setCurrentStep(session, modelAndView, ToogleStep.step38);
        String view = "redirect:/home/step38";
        modelAndView.setViewName(view);   

        // upload multiple files.       
          for(MultipartFile file:files){   
            String fileName= file.getOriginalFilename();
```

and then you will be able to access bytes and filename. Give this a try.
Atleast by looking at your problem I can suggest and if you can give more specific error, I can help.